# C# - Implementing Hotkeys in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut

I tried following code:

```
 protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control)
        {
            // Show the hotkey on the buttons with ctrl hotkeys
        }
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Control | Keys.S:
                // Execute the Ctrl + S button action
                btnSettingsSave_Click(this, null);
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

to save my setting in the GUI by pressing CTRL+S. Now that works fine but I wanted to put in more hot keys (for example CTRL+F). How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't just add case for `Keys.Control | Keys.F` in `ProcessCmdKey`?